# change target of javascript to div

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

I have some img tags with id's but through validating my code I realized that the tags were missing a src. The only problem is, is that in my javascript these img id's are targeted and when I changed them to a div instead the images disappeared.

Basically this page is staff profiles with images and content, the user clicks an arrow and it goes to the next profile. How the code works is that the images are in an external javascript file and when I click something on page and inspect the html I saw that the image appears within the image tags in HTML.This javascript was given to me so I am not sure what to change, I don't know much about javascript. Let me know if any clarification or code is needed, this is very difficult to explain as I don't understand what is going on.

HTML -the problem

```
    <img id='staff_image' class='staff_image'></img>
    <img id='staff_name' class='staff_name'></img>
```

HTML -the page

```
<div id='staff_slider' class='slider'>

    <div class='staff_container'>
        <img id='staff_image' class='staff_image' src"#" alt="image"
    </div>
        <img id='staff_name' class='staff_name' src"#" alt="image"></div>
        <div id='staff_details' class='staff_details'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='slider_navigation'>

        <img class='navLeft' src='../assets/images/staff_profile/slider/navLeft.png' alt= "nav left" onclick='navigate(-1);'/>
        <img class='navRight' src='../assets/images/staff_profile/slider/navRight.png' alt="nav right" onclick='navigate(1);'/>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="staff_profiles.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<script>
    navigate(0);
</script>
```

JAVASCRIPT- slider.js (this is for two arrow buttons that scroll through the profiles)

```
    var slider_index = 0;

    function navigate(direction){
        slider_index += direction;

        if(slider_index < 0)
        {
            slider_index = profiles.length - 1;
        }
        else if(slider_index == profiles.length)
        {
            slider_index = 0;
        }

        loadProfile(profiles[slider_index]);
    }

    function loadProfile(profile)
    {
        var staff_image = document.getElementById('staff_image');
        staff_image.src = imgPath + profile.img;

        var staff_name = document.getElementById('staff_name');
        staff_name.src = titlePath + profile.title;

        var staff_details = document.getElementById('staff_details');
        staff_details.innerHTML = profile.details;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT - staff_profiles.js (seperate file, these are the links to the images needed for the profiles, the content are in strings)

```
var imgPath = "../assets/images/staff_profile/staff/";
var titlePath = "../assets/images/staff_profile/titles/";

var profiles =
[
    //
    {
        img:"fin.jpg",
        title:"fin.png",
        details:"<p>Stunt pilot with the Red Arrows (UK airforce stunt team), has served in combat choppers in 3 recent wars, and fears nothing except small dogs and single women.</p>" +
                "<p>Owns an Extra EA-200 for the ultimate full stunt flight experience, and flies all our other fixed wing craft much more sedately when required. And, yes, that is his real name. He's Irish and he doesn't want to talk about it.</p>"
    },
    //
    {
        img:"hans.jpg",
        title:"hans.png",
        details:"<p>Hans has flown almost everything there is to fly. Hanshas has flown almost everything there is to fly. He first took the controls of a small plane at 12 years old, and flew solo when he was 14. After a few years flying anything anywhere he settled into a series of test pilot jobs but left that because he prefers company when hes in the air.</p>"
    },
    //
    {
        img:"john.jpg",
        title:"john.png",
        details:"<p>With over 10,000 hours piloting helicopters in the bush and mountains of the Southern Alps for deer recovery and mountain rescue operations, Doc is well qualified to land you and your friends in remote parts of the country that only he knows about. He ll help you plot your route, drop extra provisions where you want them, and pick you up when your done.</p>"
    },
    {
        img:"wendy.jpg",
        title:"wendy.png",
        details:"<p>13 years commercial pilot in Africa, Russia and South America, during which she survived 3 crashes (none her own fault, she maintains). Owns a Cessna-172Skyhawk P that is ideal for low level sight seeing, rides a Harley and is a ski instructor during the seas</p>"
    }
];
```

Comment: `<img id='staff_image' class='staff_image' src"#" alt="image"`??

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following lines in the `loadProfile function`

```
var staff_image = document.getElementById('staff_image');
var myimg = staff_image.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
myimg.src = imgPath + profile.img;
```

The HTML could be like this

```
<div id='staff_image'>
     <img  src"#" alt="image"/>
 </div>
```

Hope it's useful to you